# Mysql2::Error: Field 'key' doesn't have a default value after rails 5 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After upgrading to rails 5.2 and running rake db:migrate I get the error below

`ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: Mysql2::Error: Field 'key' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO 'ar_internal_metadata'`

I understand this is a new thing in rails 5 and above to prevent potential data loss in production. I can not find anywhere in the schema or migrations where this table is generated. It creates the key column with no default value and it can not be changed since it's a primary key. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I discovered that the values in the auto-generated `ar_internal_metadata` table only get set if you have an active migration while running rake db:migrate. The workaround is to set the values manually in the table so:

key -> environment and value -> production

hope this helps someone else.